# WebView not displaying dynamic part of website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I am having a great deal of troubles trying to display a webpage in WebView. I am displaying

http://meteo.arso.gov.si/met/en/app/webmet/

If you open the page in browser you can see it loads the main webapp after some time (the popup about technical problems is not there except for today). I tried opening it on browser on my Android device and it loads up properly. However, as said, displaying it in the WebView doesn't load the page properly - the webpp is missing. I am guessing WebView does not handle AJAX/JS. Why and what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable JavaScript for you webview with: `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` and see if any difference.
If the problems persist, then most probably that page isn't optimized for mobile and there's little you can do  about.

Comment: Wow, this was simple. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes to get past the limit ;) Thanks again.